# Why Swift draws borders so inaccurate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, border

[image]

How can I avoid from those corner radius border shadow(or I do not know how to call it)? Why it's not smooth?

Inside of my cell class I do(UITableViewCell):

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 225.0/255.0, green: 225.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: this pic is from simulator?

Comment: Try to scale your simulator to 100% by pressing key `command with 1`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38565134/4209778

Comment: @Mr.UB yes, but the same thing on the device

Comment: @NDoc the same thing on my device